# Update em PL/SQL

Tags: pl-sql

Dado duas tabelas, a de produtos e a de pedidos, estou tentando atualizar(update) a descrição do produto da tabela produtos quando o status do produto estiver 'INATIVO' e o status da tabela pedidos estiver 'FECHADO'

```
create table PEDIDOS
(
  CLIENTE_ID NUMBER not null,
  PRODUTO_ID NUMBER not null,
  DT_INSTAL  DATE not null,
  STATUS     VARCHAR2(40),
  PEDIDO_ID  NUMBER not null
)

create table PRODUTOS
(
  PRODUTO_ID NUMBER not null,
  DESCRICAO  VARCHAR2(40) not null,
  VALOR      VARCHAR2(13) not null,
  STATUS     VARCHAR2(13) not null,
  TIPO       VARCHAR2(1)
)
```

Por exemplo, eu tenho um produto de id 1 e descricao 'televisao', caso essa televisao esteja inativa e na tabela pedidos (de acordo com o id) estiver fechado, desejo alterar a descricao para qualquer outro nome.
Como faço pra juntar duas tabelas no comando UPDATE? Nçao estou conseguindo, se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: ressaltando o comentario do @R.Santos , aqui tem um exemplo de uma trigger com multiplos updates http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-sql-l/update-multiple-tables-in-a-single-statement-1958597

Comment: E o perguntador sumiu ...

Answer (score 0):

O comando [update](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) só pode ser aplicado a uma tabela por vez.
Caso você queira garantir que os dois irão ocorrer juntos, você pode utilizar uma transação. Ou você pode disparar uma trigger que após o primeiro update, verifique a sua condição e realize o segundo update.